# React Router DOM + Flowbite NavBar: problem with links

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, tailwind-css, flowbite

I would like to use [React Router DOM](https://reactrouter.com/) alongside [Flowbite React](https://flowbite-react.com/). I am trying to build a navbar.

```
import {Link, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
import {Navbar} from "flowbite-react";
...
const location = useLocation();
...
<Link to="/page">
    <Navbar.Link active={location.pathname === "/page"}>
        Link
    </Navbar.Link>
</Link>
```

It works, but I got warnings:

```
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.
```

I understand why it happens (because `Link` and `Navbar.Link` both contain `<a>`), but I have no idea how to fix these warnings.

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: The short answer is to use one or the other. It's not at all clear why you're using both.

Comment: Based on the `Navbar.Link` component [source](https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite-react/blob/main/src/lib/components/Navbar/NavbarLink.tsx) it is a standalone link component, same as the `Link` component from `react-router-dom`. Use one or the other.

Comment: I think the best you could do is to take the `classNames` logic of the `Navbar.Link` implementation and apply it to the `classname` prop of a RRD `Link`, or `NavLink` since it handles active links by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution in the usage of `useLinkClickHandler`:

```
import {useLinkClickHandler, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
import {Navbar} from "flowbite-react";

export interface AppNavLinkProps {
    to: string;
    text: string;
}

export default function AppNavLink(props: AppNavLinkProps) {
    const location = useLocation();
    const clickHandler = useLinkClickHandler(props.to);
    
    return <span onClick={clickHandler}>
        <Navbar.Link href={props.to} active={location.pathname === props.to}>
            {props.text}
        </Navbar.Link>
    </span>;
}
...
<AppNavLink to="/page" text="Link" />
```

In that way I can get rid of `Link` and leave only `Navbar.Link`, but preserve `Link` functionality (don't reload a page when the link was clicked, but use History API).

Answer (score 0):

The `as` prop provides you the ability to transform the Flowbite components into another component or HTML element. This prop accepts a string representing an HTML tag or a functional React component.

```
import {Link, useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
import {Navbar} from "flowbite-react";
...
const location = useLocation();
...
<Link to="/page">
    <Navbar.Link active={location.pathname === "/page"} as="div">
        Link
    </Navbar.Link>
</Link>
```